# Understanding Gerrit dependencies

Tags: git, gerrit

I'm not quite understanding the "dependency" concept in Gerrit.

If I have a change-set with number 230693,
and if *refs/changes/93/230693/2* is it's latest patch-set,
is the "dependency" of my change-set *refs/changes/93/230693* ?

In other words,

Is the Gerrit definition of "dependency" simply a git concept, or can there be ad-hoc dependencies that might not necessarily be reachable by the latest patch-set of the given change-set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dependencies of a Gerrit change are its parent changes (commits), i.e. the changes that must be submitted before the change in question can be submitted. Gerrit wants to merge changes to the designated destination branch, but because of how git works that would also include any parent changes. Allowing that would sidestep the review of those changes. If a change's parent commit is already submitted and reachable from the branch there's no dependency to worry about.

So, Gerrit's dependency concept is based on the commit lineage and isn't arbitrarily chosen.

Note that none if this applies for the Cherry Pick [submit type](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/project-configuration.html#submit_type). With that submit type chosen the dependencies of a change will be ignored.